# Elasticsearch return searched word

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using `fuzzy` and want elasticsearch to return the searched word not just the hit. 
When i am searching for the word `dogo` and my fuzzy search finds the word `dog` i want to know that it was `dogo` who found it.

data:

```
{ "index": { "_id":1 }}
{ "title": "The quick brown fox", "price":5 }
{ "index": { "_id":2 }}
{ "title": "The quick blue dog", "price":7 }
{ "index": { "_id":3 }}
{ "title": "The slow brown dog", "price":5 }
```

query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
    "should": [
        {
          "fuzzy": {
                  "title": "dogo"
                      }

          },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
                  "title": "fox"
                      }
          }
        ]
    }

  },
  "highlight" : {
      "fields" : {
          "title":{
              "pre_tags": [
                "===>"
              ],
              "post_tags": [
                "<==="
              ],
              "fragment_size": 200,
              "number_of_fragments": 100
          }
      }
   }  
}
```

This query will return `===>dog<===` but don't know if `dogo` found it.

Does anyone know how to do this or an idea? 
I want my output to be something like `dog : dogo`.

Comment: Why is this question is tagged "python"? I think it's pretty generic "elasticsearch".

I don't know if an elastic version is maybe appropriate here. It still works in v.8.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) for this, by giving a name to each of your queries. In the results, each hit will feature a `matched_queries` array containing the names of the queries that matched (e.g. `dogo` and `fox` below).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "name": {
              "value": "dogo",
              "_name": "dogo"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "name": {
              "value": "fox",
              "_name": "fox"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title": {
        "pre_tags": [
          "===>"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
          "<==="
        ],
        "fragment_size": 200,
        "number_of_fragments": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Named queries is the right choice to understand your query name in results. You could also try suggestion if you want to know the possible corrected terms for your query term.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
    "should": [
        {
          "fuzzy": {
                  "title": "dogo"
                      }

          },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
                  "title": "fox"
                      }
          }
        ]
    }

  },
  "highlight" : {
      "fields" : {
          "title":{
              "pre_tags": [
                "===>"
              ],
              "post_tags": [
                "<==="
              ],
              "fragment_size": 200,
              "number_of_fragments": 100
          }
      }
   }  ,
 "suggest" : {
    "title_suggestion" : {
      "text" : "fox dogo",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "title"
      }
    }
  }
}
```