# find out which should query returned true in elastic-search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to find a way which should query returned true in my elastic search query
Supposed I have a bool query consists of the should conditions I want to find which should happened for every of my result

````
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "status": {
                    "query": "ACTIVE"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "status": {
                    "query": "MENU_UPDATE"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }

      ]
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48031281/4604579 (hint: use named queries)

Comment: Cool, glad that helped!