# How can I include query string in elastic search response

Tags: elasticsearch

front end  is  sending async calls to  Elastic server. To match the responses, I would like to add the  query  string in the elastic response json.   Does  Elastic search have  any option to include the  query string in the response ?

Comment: This thread should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877453/elasticsearch-return-searched-word/48031281#48031281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html). You can assign a name to each query which will appear in the result

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "this OR thus",
      "_name":"query1"
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index50",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "VDBsK3IBpnSikKlzkKY3",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "this"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "query1"    ---> name passed in query
        ]
      }
    ]
```

To search in url:

```
localhost:9200/_search?pretty&source={"query": {"query_string": {
      "query": "this OR thus", "_name":"query1"} }}
&source_content_type=application/json
```

Comment: This  works from curl. However I  need a  browser URL.   Is it  possible ? For example, localshostt/_search?pretty=true&q=cityname:chicago&_name:chicago

Answer (score 0):

The documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html doesn’t mention it anyway.

I think that such an option does NOT exist since several types of query exist and for most of them there is more than a query string.